# error when installing Ruby 3.1.4 on Mac M1 with asdf

Tags: ruby, asdf-vm, ruby-build

I'm trying to install ruby 3.1.4 with asdf on a Macbook Pro but am getting a constant error of:

```
6557 compiling ripper.c
6558 readline.c:1903:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
6559                                     rl_username_completion_function);
6560                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6561                                     rl_username_completion_function
6562 readline.c:79:42: note: expanded from macro 'rl_username_completion_function'
6563 # define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
```

I have readline and it's unclear why my updated version of readline is causing this error. Any ideas of a next step? I see some people uninstalling asdf and homebrew but would rather not do such an extreme process.

Comment: What do you use to control ruby versions on your mac?
I didn't faced with this issue, but I'm using ruby 3.1.4 on M1. Try to use RVM.

Comment: @MykhailoMelnyk I was using asdf. The issue of having some Rosetta libraries and some arm64 libraries is what caused this (having used Rosetta when I first got this Mac and many libraries still being intel only). I ended up removing brew and asdf and reinstalling and seems to be working fine.

I was hoping for a simpler solution but honestly reinstalling asdf and homebrew wasn't that big of a deal.